# Serde: use container #[serde(default)], but with some required fields

Tags: rust, serde

I have a struct that uses [the `#[serde(default)]` container attribute](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#default).

But there is one field that should be required (if this field doesn't exist in the incoming data, the deserializer should error out instead of falling back to default value).

```rust
#[serde(default)]
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Example {
  important: i32, // <-- I want this field to be required.
  a: i32, //  <-- If this field isn't in the incoming data, fallback to the default value.
  b: i32, //  <-- If this field isn't in the incoming data, fallback to the default value.
  c: i32, //  <-- If this field isn't in the incoming data, fallback to the default value.
}
```

***Edit:***

The information below isn't correct. The `#[serde(default)]` *field* attribute does not take the default value of the struct type, but rather of each field's type. (i.e. `impl Default for Example` isn't used. `impl Default for i32` is used).

***End Edit.***

I could use [the `#[serde(default)]` field attribute](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#default) like this:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Example {
  important: i32,
  #[serde(default)]
  a: i32,
  #[serde(default)]
  b: i32,
  #[serde(default)]
  c: i32,
}
```

So `important` would be required, while `a`, `b`, and `c` would have default values.

But copy-pasting `#[serde(default)]` for all but one field doesn't seem like a good solution (my struct has ~10 fields).
Is there a better way?

Comment: Is it an either all or none situation? Because what would happen if `important` and `b` are specified e.g. the following JSON `{ "important": 1, "b": 2 }`. Should `a` and `c` still be default. If yes, then repeating it 10 times, might be the shortest solution. **Edit:** I was about to suggest using a second struct and `serde(default)` + `serde(flatten)` but that doesn't seem to be supported (see [issue #1626](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/1626))

Comment: My question was unclear. Yes, if there is only `important` and `b`, `a` and `c` should be default. Your suggestion to use `serde(flatten)` would require an additional layer when accessing the fields, like `example.data.a`. I've decided to just copy paste ten times.

Comment: Given that `serde(default)` + `serde(flatten)` is currently unsupported, then yeah, the most straightforward solution is just to use `serde(default)` x10

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Responding to your edit you can utilize `#[serde(default = "path")]` to set the default values for each field. The path is to a function that returns the default value for that field.

Reference: https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html

Example:

```
const A_DEFAULT: i32 = 1;
const B_DEFAULT: i32 = 2;
const C_DEFAULT: i32 = 3;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Example {
  important: i32,
  #[serde(default = "a_default")]
  a: i32,
  #[serde(default = "b_default")]
  b: i32,
  #[serde(default = "c_default")]
  c: i32,
}

fn a_default() -> i32{
  A_DEFAULT
}
fn b_default() -> i32{
  B_DEFAULT
}
fn c_default() -> i32{
  C_DEFAULT
}
```

Comment: Update: you can now also use const fns for this: `const fn _default_true() -> bool { true }` and then `#[serde(default = "_default_true")]  pub enable: bool,`.